# How to group by this table?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

**My Table**

```
PERSON  |  car type |   color  |  make
 ------------------------------------
mark    |   sedan   |          |
kevin   |   sedan   |          |
kevin   |           | blue     |
kevin   |           |          | honda
john    |           | gray     |
john    |           |          | toyota
charlie |   suv     |          |
charlie |           | orange   |
charlie |           |          | volvo
charlie |  sedan    |          |
charlie |           | blue     |
```

i wanted to group it by person but its not a group by expression so

**expected output**

```
PERSON  |  car type |   color  |  make
 ------------------------------------
mark    |   sedan   |          |
kevin   |   sedan   |  blue    |  honda
john    |           |  gray    |  toyota
charlie |   suv     |  orange  |  volvo
charlie |   sedan   |  blue    |
```

Comment: This is not the way to store data in Oracle. Inserts way too much redundancy. Instead you can remove redundancy and make it to normal at some level. Because of this redundancy simple query (you asking ) will take longer time for some thousand or million records.

Comment: from the data provided for Charlie, how do you know the suv is orange and the sedan is blue, and not the other way around (suv is blue, sedan is orange)? Do you assign any meaning to the ORDER of rows in your input table? If you do, that is a serious mistake (rows are not ordered), UNLESS there is additional data or rules you didn't share with us. Please clarify (either here or in the other, almost identical question you posted the same day).

Answer (score 1):

we want person column as unique to group by on person name column but charlie named record is two time with double grouping so its not possible you have to rename that column to got that output, i have solved with this on this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0f01/2) check.

Answer (score 0):

if the other fields contain either blank or only one value, then you can safely use this query.

```
select PERSON, max(car_type) as Car_type, max(color) as color, max(Make) as Make 
from YourTable
group by PERSON
```

Comment: it has different values

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
Select a.person,a.car_type,b.color,c.Make from (
select PERSON, car_type
From yourtable  
Group by Person,car_type
) as a
join (
select PERSON, color
From yourtable 
Group by Person,color) as b on a.person=b.person
join (
select PERSON, Make
From yourtable 
Group by Person,Make) as c on a.person= c.person
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, only possible solution is, **update `car_type`, `color` and `make` columns wherever needed instead of having a new entries or have a primary key column**. Because, there is no way by which you could associate other column value to get your expected output (considering example of person name charlie). This way you could reduce unnecessary insertion and total number of rows.